# how to free dynamic memory allocated inside function after finishing execution

Tags: c

how to free dynamic memory allocated inside function
after finishing execution

i allocated two char *  str2R & str4R
and my function is

```
char * MMP(char * index)
{

    char* str1= "AT+CMGR=";
    char* str2R = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str1)+ strlen(index) );
    strcpy(str2R, str1);
    strcat(str2R, index);

    char* str3="\r";
    char* str4R = (char *) malloc(1 + strlen(str2R)+ strlen(str3) );
    strcpy(str4R, str2R);
    strcat(str4R, str3);


    return str4R;

};
```

when i call

```
  free(str2R);
  free(str4R);
```

in main or in another file after calling the function
this error appears

error: str2R undeclared (first use in this function)

thanks in advance

Comment: Free it *before* you return.

Comment: what about the return value ??
if i do this.....can i access the varible pointed by this pointer after execution??

Comment: The variable names str2R and str4R are out of scope after the function returns. You return str4R, so it's value is available in whatever variable you saved the return value. You can free str2R before exiting, as it is not be used outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to allocate two `char*` buffers, one will suffice.  Then caller needs to `free()` the returned `char*` when it is done using it.

Try this:

```
char * MMP(char * index)
{
    char* str1 = "AT+CMGR=";
    char* str3 = "\r";

    char* str2R = (char *) malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(index) + strlen(str3) + 1);
    if (str2R)
    {
        strcpy(str2R, str1);
        strcat(str2R, index);
        strcat(str2R, str3);
    }

    return str2R;
}
```

```
char *str = MMP("some value");
...
free(str);
```

With that said, the logic inside of `MMP()` would be better served using `snprintf()` instead of `strcpy()` and `strcat()`:

```
char * MMP(char * index)
{
    char* fmt = "AT+CMGR=%s\r";
    char* str2R = NULL;

    int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, index);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        ++len;
        str2R = (char *) malloc(len);
        if (str2R)
            snprintf(str2R, len, fmt, index);
    }

    return str2R;
}
```